# open file dialog not working from Installer class in c# application

Tags: c#, installation, windows-installer

I have designed my project MSi file through Visual Studio 2010 Setup and deployment project in which I added one custom action. In the custom action, I am opening OpenFile dialog . It is working fine from inside Application. But from Installer it hangs out.

```
public override void Install(IDictionary stateSaver)
        {
            base.Install(stateSaver);
             OpenFileDialog fdlg = new OpenFileDialog();
            fdlg.Title = " Dialog";
             ....
             ....
            if (fdlg.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                tempPath = fdlg.SafeFileName;
                mappingPath = fdlg.FileName;
            }
    }
```

Comment: "Hangs out".  Does that mean you do or _do not_ see the dialog displayed on-screen?

Comment: The application is not responding..can see mouse loader loading...

Comment: Yeah, if I recall from my days using Installshield, when you're CA out to a DLL, you cannot do GUI stuff (at least not reliably).  We always set return flags and reacted within InstallScript for all such GUI work.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [Soumitra Mondal's WebLog](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2012/12/31/10059279.aspx)

`FileDialog.ShowDialog` requires **STA thread**, whereas MSI is running as **MTA thread**.  In Order to achieve this you will need to start a ***STA background thread and call the dialog from that thread***.

You need to change the your call from

`DialogResult ret = fdlg.ShowDialog();` to

```
DialogResult ret = STAShowDialog(fdlg);
```